# How to reverse a custom list in SML?

Tags: recursion, sml, custom-data-type

My custom datatype is defined as follows: datatype `'a mylist = NIL | CONS of 'a * 'a mylist;`

Been trying for hours but can't figure out how to reverse such a list.

My code that doesn't work:

```
fun reverse NIL = NIL
| reverse (CONS(head,tail)) = reverse tail @ [head];
```

Here is the function call:

```
reverse (CONS(4,CONS(3,CONS(2,NIL))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of the append operator will increase the time complexity of this solution. I would instead use a helper function in order to perform a tail-recursive call whereby the list is reversed in a stack-like manner.

e.g.

```ml
fun reverse xs =
let
  fun revhelp NIL ys = ys
    | revhelp (CONS(x,xs)) ys = revhelp xs (CONS(x,ys))
in
  revhelp xs NIL
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the builtin append (`@`) and lists (`[head]`) with your own list type.

You need `CONS (head, NIL)` instead of `[head]`, and you need to write your own

```
append: 'a mylist -> 'a mylist -> 'a mylist
```

or

```
append: ('a mylist * 'a mylist) -> 'a mylist
```

Implementing `append` left as an exercise.